# Accidentally deleted all my commits on Git — what happened?

Tags: git, github

Okay let me start off by saying that I hate git so much. I was getting error message after error message and it resulted in every commit on my project being deleted. Here are the recent commands that I did:

```
git push origin master
```

which gave me an error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to '[repository link here]'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

then I found a resource online and did this:

```
git pull origin master
git push -f origin master
```

and then everything was gone except that one commit. What do I do to recover?

Comment: `git reflog` might still contain the old commits. Stop hating git and it will love you back!

Comment: http://effectif.com/git/recovering-lost-git-commits details the process of recovering the lost commits.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. But dang, git reflog is only showing that one commit :(

Comment: Is this remote a github remote? Another computer? Do you have other team members?

Answer (score 0):

Git was warning you that what you were about to is destructive.  When you did `git push -f` that is a forced push and you were telling Git to go ahead and do that.  Whatever you had locally will replace whatever was in the remote.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm a git noob, so I had no idea that was the case. Is there any way to get those commits back, or am I out of luck?

Comment: There is always a way. Git "never" actually deletes anything (within 30 days). Those commit will still exist on the server. Git does have a poor UI. You are best learning at least a little about how it works before using it.

Comment: "...am I out of luck?" - Probably not but the particulars may depend on the server and who manages it.  If the remote is at GitHub, send them a support request and they will likely get you straightened out.  If it is your own server or one managed by your company, you will need to talk with someone who understands Git and has access to do the recovery. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you tried to push the first time, you had commits on the remote repo. Git was unable to push, because you are required to pull the changes to your local repo and merge them before you can push your new commits up.

However, by using the -f you forced the remote repo to overwrite the commits that were on the server.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to recover the lost commits.